# Merge two files using awk and write the output

Tags: bash, awk, export-to-csv

I have two files with common field. I want to merge the two files with common field and write the merged file into another file using `awk` in linux command.

**file1**

```
412234$name1$value1$mark1
413233$raja$$mark2
414444$$$
```

**file2**

```
412234$sum$file2$address$street
413233$sum2$file32$address2$street2$path
414444$$$$
```

These sample files are seperated by `$` and output merged file also will be in `$`. Also these rows have the empty field.

I tried the script using `join`:

```
   join -t "$" out2.csv out1.csv  |sort -un > file3.csv
```

But there is total number mismatching happened.

Tried with `awk`:

**myawk.awk**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f 
NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next} {print a[FNR],$2,$3}
```

I ran it

```
awk -f myawk.awk out2.csv out1.csv > file3.csv
```

It was also taking too much time. Not responding.

Here `out2.csv` is master file and we have to compare with `out1.csv`

Could you please help me to write the merged files into another file?

Comment: To use join, the input files must already be sorted.  That you are piping to `sort -n` indicates that perhaps they are not sorted correctly.  Try sorting them lexicographically (not numerically), then use join, then sort the output numerically.

Answer (score 3):

Run the following using `bash`. This gives you the equivalent of a full outer join

```
 join -t'$' -a 1 -a 2 <(sort -k1,1 -t'$' out1.csv ) <(sort -k1,1 -t'$' out2.csv )
```

Comment: Yeah this is working the problem is the first file line is writing and then the second file line is writing into next line..So the columns are not merging properly..Because after i merged this file again i have to merge with another file(out3.csv) based on the same first column field ..

Comment: Saravanan, join command returns matching lines from 2 files side by side. You sure your lines are not terminated by CRLF characters?

Answer (score 1):

You were in the good direction with the `awk` solution. The main point was to change `FS` to split fields with `$`:

Content of `script.awk`:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        ## Split fields with "$".
        FS = "$"
    }

    ## Save lines from second file, the first field as the index of the
    ## array, and rest of the line as the value.
    FNR == NR {
        file2[ $1 ] = substr( $0, index( $0, "$" ) )
        next
    }

    ## Print when keys from both files match.
    FNR < NR {
        if ( $1 in file2 ) {
            printf "%s$%s\n", $0, file2[ $1 ]
        }
    }
' out2.csv out1.csv
```

Output:

```
412234$name1$value1$mark1$$sum$file2$address$street
413233$raja$$mark2$$sum2$file32$address2$street2$path
414444$$$$$$$$
```